# How to select non-anonymous feedback programmatically in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I want moodle feedback to select non-anonymous option programmatically. How can i do that? Below is the code:

```
$options=array();
    $options[1]  = get_string('anonymous', 'feedback');
    $options[2]  = get_string('non_anonymous', 'feedback');
    $mform->addElement('select',
                       'anonymous',
                       get_string('anonymous_edit', 'feedback'),
                       $options);
```

Any reference or help will be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setDefault

```
    $options=array();
    $options[1]  = get_string('anonymous', 'feedback');
    $options[2]  = get_string('non_anonymous', 'feedback');
    $mform->addElement('select',
                       'anonymous',
                       get_string('anonymous_edit', 'feedback'),
                       $options);

    $mform->setDefault('anonymous', 2);
```